# SQL Insert doesn't work for some reason

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I remove '$user' and by this works perfectly

```
$query = $db -> query("INSERT INTO posts (title, body, tags, published, date, by) VALUES       
('$title', '$body', '$tags', '$published', '$date', '$user')");
```

User is varchar(11)

when I print_r $user I get the value I want

I am not sure what is going on, `by` is at the end of the table.

Sorry if this question is stupid.

peace

Comment: also, be careful SQL Injection. Make sure you escape your input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `BY` is a Reserved keyword and happens to be the name of the column. In order to avoid syntax error, you need to escape it using backtick,

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, body, tags, published, date, `by`) VALUES (...)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

I rather change the column name to avoid problem from getting back again `:D`

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

And addition, you can also put a backtick on the "date" column since it is also a reserved word..

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, body, tags, published, `date`, `by`) VALUES (...)
```

Well in my case I really don't prefer using backtick but it's really helpful in avoiding syntax errors..

Comment: you are right that `date` is a reserved keyword but it can be used even without wrapping it with backtick.

Comment: yeah, you're also right! But well, in the case of formality and consistency, that can be applied.. well, it's true that it is not necessary though.. :) anyway, thanks for the reply and additional info..